# Reformat SD card

Tags: sd-card, mkfs, fat32

I need to reformat an SD card back to factory status.

SD card filesystem used for media has become corrupted.  Accessing a certain directory causes the filesystem to be remounted readonly, and it cannot be deleted.  fsck.vfat says that it does not have a repair method for the specific type of corruption.

Comment: `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/whatever bs=2048 count=1` should be enough to wipe it clean. Be careful not to do that to your internal disk.

Comment: SD cards are sold ready to use in devices which have no formatting code.  It's not just a convention, there's actually a standard for it.  Use of any other filesystem is not supported by the standard - cheap SD cards make assumptions based on it. This is referenced in my answer. I am after the standard formatting, not an unformatted partition that cannot be used to store files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

REMINDER: commands like this are designed to overwrite filesystem data.  You must take extreme care to avoid targeting the wrong disk.

EDIT:

Before formatting the card, you may also want to perform a discard operation.

```
blkdiscard /dev/mmcblk0
```

This might improve performance - the same as TRIM on a SATA SSD.  Resetting the block remapping layer might also theoretically help resolve corruption at or around that layer, although this method is not as good as a dedicated full device erase command (SATA secure erase). This may not be suppported by all card readers.  On my Dell Latitude laptop, it reset the card to all-zeros in one second.  This implies that on this card it only affected the block remapping layer; it cannot have performed an immediate erase of the entire 16GB of flash.

---

> MicroSD cards contain one or more flash chips and a small microprocessor that acts as an interface between the SD card specification and the flash chip(s). Cards are typically formatted from the factory for near-optimal performance. However, most operating systems default partitioning and formatting utilities treat the cards like traditional hard drives. What works for traditional hard drives results in degraded performance and lifetime for flash-based cards

http://3gfp.com/wp/2014/07/formatting-sd-cards-for-speed-and-lifetime/

A script is available for cards up to 32GiB.  I have modified it to work with current versions of `sfdisk`.  Running `file -s` on the resulting partition returned the same numbers as before, except for the number of heads/sectors per track.  Those are not used by current operating systems, although apparently some embedded bootloaders will require specific values.

```
#! /bin/sh
# fdisk portion of script based on mkcard.sh v0.4
# (c) Copyright 2009 Graeme Gregory <dp@xora.org.uk>
# Additional functionality by Steve Sakoman
# (c) Copyright 2010-2011 Steve Sakoman <steve@sakoman.com>
# Updated by Alan Jenkins (2016)
# Licensed under terms of GPLv2
#
# Parts of the procudure base on the work of Denys Dmytriyenko
# http://wiki.omap.com/index.php/MMC_Boot_Format

# exit if any command fails
set -e

export LC_ALL=C

format_whole_disk_fat32() {
    if ! id | grep -q root; then
        echo "This utility must be run prefixed with sudo or as root"
        return 1
    fi

    local DRIVE=$1

    # Make sure drive isn't mounted    
    # so hopefully this will fail e.g. if we're about to blow away the root filesystem
    for mounted in $(findmnt -o source | grep "^$DRIVE") ; do
        umount "$mounted"
    done    

    # Make sure current partition table is deleted
    wipefs --all $DRIVE

    # Get disk size in bytes
    local SIZE=$(fdisk -l $DRIVE | grep Disk | grep bytes | awk '{print $5}')
    echo DISK SIZE – $SIZE bytes

    # Note: I'm changing our default cluster size to 32KiB since all of
    # our 8GiB cards are arriving with 32KiB clusters. The manufacturers
    # may know something that we do not *or* they're trading speed for
    # more space.
    local CLUSTER_SIZE_KB=32
    local CLUSTER_SIZE_IN_SECTORS=$(( $CLUSTER_SIZE_KB * 2 ))

    # This won't work for drives bigger than 32GiB because
    # 32GiB / 64kiB clusters = 524288 FAT entries
    # 524288 FAT entries * 4 bytes / FAT = 2097152 bytes
    # 2097152 bytes / 512 bytes = 4096 sectors for FAT size
    # 4096 * 2 = 8192 sectors for both FAT tables which leaves no
    # room for the BPB sector
    if [ $SIZE -ge $(( ($CLUSTER_SIZE_KB / 2) * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 )) ]; then
        echo -n "This drive is too large, >= $(($CLUSTER_SIZE_KB / 2))GiB, for this "
        echo "formatting routine."
        return 1
    fi

    # Align partitions for SD card performance/wear optimization
    # Summary: start 1st partition at sector 8192 (4MiB) and align FAT32
    #          data to start at 8MiB (4MiB logical)
    #          There's a document that explains why, but its too long to
    #          reproduce here.
    {
    echo 8192,,0x0C,*
    } | sfdisk -uS -q $DRIVE

    sleep 1

    if [ -b ${DRIVE}1 ]; then
        PART1=${DRIVE}1
    elif [ -b ${DRIVE}p1 ]; then
        PART1=${DRIVE}p1
    else
        echo "Improper partitioning on $DRIVE"
        return 1
    fi

    # Delete any old filesystem visible in new partition
    wipefs --all $PART1

    # Format FAT32 with 64kiB clusters (128 * 512)
    # Format once to get the calculated FAT size
    local FAT_SIZE=$(mkdosfs -F 32 -s $CLUSTER_SIZE_IN_SECTORS -v ${PART1} | \
        sed -n -r -e '/^FAT size is/ s,FAT size is ([0-9]+) sectors.*$,\1,p')

    # Calculate the number of reserved sectors to pad in order to align
    # the FAT32 data area to 4MiB
    local RESERVED_SECTORS=$(( 8192 - 2 * $FAT_SIZE ))

    # Format again with padding
    mkdosfs -F 32 -s $CLUSTER_SIZE_IN_SECTORS -v -R $RESERVED_SECTORS ${PART1}

    # Uncomment to label filesystem
    #fatlabel ${PART1} BOOT
}

#set -x

format_whole_disk_fat32 "$@"
```

Comment: FYI if someone has an sdcard bigger than 32GiB: You'll need to change `local RESERVED_SECTORS=$(( 8192 - 2 * $FAT_SIZE ))` to `local RESERVED_SECTORS=$((  131072 - 2 * $FAT_SIZE ))`. Also remove `return 1` to continue after the error (warning) about the disk being too big.  I'm not sure if BPB will still work, but at least the first data offset will be aligned to 4MiB boundary.  You could change `131072` to any multiple of `8192` if you have an even bigger card that needs FAT32.  It worked for a 512 GiB card, now my Canon Powershot SX230HS will boot [CHDK](https://chdk.fandom.com/wiki/CHDK)!