# Format microSDCard which has an OS written on it

Tags: partition, mkfs

I've got a 32G micro SDCard which I created a bootable ubuntu installation on it for use on a home server some while ago. I want to format it to FAT32 but have been unable to do so with either gParted/[parted](https://computingforgeeks.com/format-sdcard-usb-flash-drive-on-linux-terminal/)/[format_whole_disk_fat32](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/312396/411593)/`sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb1 bs=512 count=2` + `mkfs.vfat -F32` amoung other attempts.

With the `lsblk -o +label,fstype,uuid /dev/sdb` command I still get:

```
sdb    8:16   1 29,5G  0 disk                         
├─sdb1
│      8:17   1   64M  0 part                  ext4   744e79fb-aa6e-4ea9-af08-aca3bfbeaf14
└─sdb2
       8:18   1 29,4G  0 part /media/lin       ext4   eb346c10-13c5-4e4f-8a24-8623e972f8c9
```

How do I write over the OS on the card and reformat it?

**Update**

Attempted writing over the first MB of the disk using the [mkusb tool](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick/post) and the *restore to a Standard storage device* option. I also left the tool to churn over night on the *Wipe a device (drive)* option but am still left with the same partition and contents.

The first attempt gave an error message about not being able to write the requested amount of data:

```
Error: YOu requested a partition from 1049kb to 31,7GB (sectors 2048..61831167).
The closest location we can manage is 1048kB to 1048kB (sectors 2047..2047).
```

Comment: your question is about partitioning an SD card, not about overwriting the data on the card, such as an OS ... it is not really even about formatting the partitions .... do research about partitioning SD cards

Comment: Try according to [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick/post) and if there is still a problem, analyze and try to solve it according to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035)

Comment: it would be helpful if you described why your attempts failed.

Comment: @sudodus Tried the first link: "Postrequisites - restore the USB stick" but it could only write 1024kb to disk and the remaining partitions were left intact. I'll keep this tread posted on the progress from trying out instructions from second link.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be running your commands on a partition when you actually should be running on the disk itself. Also you will often get issues when formatting if you do not properly clear the disk beforehand. A good way of doing it would be:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb
```

This will likely take a good while, so this second option should be much more than enough:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=1M count=8
```

Often syncing writes to disk is also a good idea:

```
sudo sync /dev/sdb
```

After removing the first 8MB of data you're supposed to have a card without traces of its old partition table. You can confirm it by running `lsblk` again and seeing no more partitions under the disk:

```
sdb    8:16   1 29,5G  0 disk
```

At this point `mkfs.vfat` should be able to do its magic:

```
sudo mkfs.vfat -F 32 /dev/sdb
```

Be mindful that not all devices will recognize multiple partitions on an sd card, so the best practice is to always write the partition directly to the disk, instead of creating a file system (like DOS or GPT), unless you're doing something fancy like installing an OS on it to use on a Pi.

Comment: You're correct in assuming that the use of the sdcard was for a Pi, or actually a CuBox, but still. The second `dd` command didn't wipe out the two partitions as they still appeared as separate partitions after checking with `lsblk`. I tried increasing the data amount to 64MB in thinking it would possibly overwrite the first partion yielding:
```64+0 records in
64+0 records out
67108864 bytes (67 MB, 64 MiB) copied, 6,30793 s, 10,6 MB/s
```
...but the OS contents is still on the disk.

Comment: Use the first `dd` to make sure then, if the card data still shows up after that you should reboot (I don't know how to force updating the partition table read from a disk on linux, but I saw that one day). If data still shows up you may have a computer that isn't writing data to the card, or a maybe a card that isn't writable anymore...

Perhaps `wipefs -a /dev/sdb` works also... `-a` should mean all filesystems.